# strucure of component inside table html

Tags: html, structure

I want to make a table of orders, for each row there's an arrow that show a bill details related to each order and hide when I click again on the button.

How can I make the structure of the table?

I make like this

```
<table id="customerTable">
<thead>
       <tr>
      <td>customer name </td>
      <td>order date</td>
      <td>sale point</td>
      <td>total</td>
        </tr>
</thead>

     <tr>
      <td>customer name </td>
      <td>order date</td>
      <td>sale point</td>
      <td>total</td>
          <td><a href="">show details</a></td>
      </tr>

 //also loop here as the number of bills
   <tr>
     <td>bill order/td>
     <td>product</td>
     <td>price</td>
  </tr>
```

I don't think like this structure is correct, and making div inside a table doesn't work, any suggestion please?

Comment: can you please provide how you want the output? draw the output structure here simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible structure:

```
<table id="customerTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>customer name </td>
            <td>order date</td>
            <td>sale point</td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="master">
            <td>customer name </td>
            <td>order date</td>
            <td>sale point</td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>
                <a href="">show details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="detail">
             <td colspan=5>
                 <!-- new <table> with your details of this row -->
             </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- ... more rows ... --->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J7szf/**

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/J7szf/1/

Comment: I can't make div inside a td, I tried it but the browser ignores it.

Comment: Of course you can! But check my edited post. This makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a popup near the "Show Details" Link 
**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/93/

If you want the content to be displayed in the table itself , provide here some idea on how u want the content displayed

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have an extra unneeded `<tr>` before your loop. You should have a standard table structure but hide / show the details depending on a click.

You'd better use:

- styling with css and classes the standard row and the details
- using js to hide / show rows

Actually, you could use jquery plugins to do this kind of stuff. See this example of [datatables grouping rows](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)

Jqgrid can also make some [row grouping](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

[EDIT] The easiest way to define your HTML structure is to get inspired from the HTML in these jquery plugin examples

Comment: The extra <tr> is just a copy past error, acutally I want to create the html using jQuery, but I want to know the structure before.

Comment: @Alaa: then, the easiest way is to have a look at the jquery plugin examples (like the one i gave - i'll edit my post to show some other ones) and see the HTML structures that is expected